# Function for which taking preimages preserves limit points

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, connectedness

Suppose we have a **surjection** $f : X \to Y$ between topological spaces. What is the weakest assumption on $f$, $X$ and $Y$ you can think of that endows $f$ with the following property?

> If $A \subseteq Y$ has limit point $y \in Y$ then $f^{-1}[A]$ has a limit point in $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$.

This evidently holds if $f$ is a continuous and open map, but I'd like to avoid the open map assumption if possible.

**Edit:** If we discard the open map assumption, it seems that $X$ would need to be compact; consider the continuous bijection $f : [0, 1) \to S^1$, where $f$ merely "glues" the interval into a circle (in terms of complex numbers, $f(t) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi t}$). $f(0)$ is a limit point of $f[(\frac{1}{2}, 1)]$ but $0$ is not a limit point of $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. The problem seems to be that $[0, 1)$ isn't compact...

Answer (score 2):

$f$ merely needs to be a *closed map*. That is, $f[C]$ is closed for all closed $C \subseteq X$.

**Proof.** If $y$ is a limit point of $A$ then $y \in \overline{A}$. Assume that $y \notin A$, for the alternative would be trivial. Thus $f^{-1}[A]$ is disjoint from $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$. Let $C = \overline{f^{-1}[A]}$.

$$
f[C] \supseteq A \implies f[C] = \overline{f[C]} \supseteq \overline{A} \ni y.
$$

Therefore $\overline{f^{-1}[A]} = C$ intersects $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$, and consequently $f^{-1}[A]$ has a limit point in $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$.